# iOS: SMS Donations alongside an IAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, donations

Is it allowed to accept donations in a free app that also has an In-App Purchase?

I don't want to use IAP to accept donations, I know that's not allowed.
I don't want to try to accept donations in a paid app, I know that's not allowed.

I'm building an informational app for a charity that accepts donations. They also want to have a section of the app for a sort of journal that they would like to charge for with an IAP.

Anyone been in this situation before? What's allowed, and what's not? I don't want to get to submission time and end up having to tell them they can't do what they'd planned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Heres some info from Apple that may answer your question:

> 1. Charities and contributions
>
> 21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free
>
> 21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS

[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

Comment: I know about this, but unfortunately it's not clear on whether an app with an In App Purchase is considered a free app or not. I'm hoping it is because apps with IAP are listed on the "Top Free" list in iTunes, but it wouldn't surprise me if that's considered different in some way.